# Task -> ValueTask in this case

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task, valuetask

`SubscribeToTickerAsync` is going to be invoked more than once, which makes me believe ValueTask is the better choice here. Otherwise, the impact of avoiding a single allocation of a tiny object is practically zero.

What stops me from replacing `Task` -> `ValueTask` is the following statement. Does that mean that if there are multiple awaits it's a bad idea to return ValueTask?

> ValueTask can only be awaited once, and not to be awaited concurrently. This means that each ValueTask can be consumed only once.
>
> Here the word “consume” implies that a ValueTask can asynchronously wait for (await) the operation to complete or take advantage of AsTask to convert a ValueTask to a Task. However, a ValueTask should be consumed only once, after which the ValueTask should be ignored.

`_requestManager.GetResponseAsync` is a `TaskCompletionSource<T, Y>` implementation.

`_websocketClient.SendAsync` is technically `System.Threading.Channels` implementation.

```cs
public ValueTask SendAsync(Message message)
{
    return _sendChannel.Writer.WriteAsync(message);
}
```

### Code

```cs
private async Task SendAsync(SocketRequest request)
{
    await _throttlingLimiter.WaitAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

    var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(request);
    var message = new Message(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json));
    await _websocketClient.SendAsync(message).ConfigureAwait(false);

    var responseTask = await _requestManager.GetResponseAsync(request.Id, TaskCreationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously, CancellationToken.None).ConfigureAwait(false);

    // TODO: Process that result and return it
    _logger.LogInformation("Message: {Message}", Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responseTask.Span));
}

public async Task SubscribeToTickerAsync(Func<BookPrice, ValueTask> handler)
{
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(handler);

    var request = new SocketRequest("SUBSCRIBE", new[] { "btcusdt@bookTicker" }, GetNextRequestId());
    await SendAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false);

    if (!_subscriptionManager.AddSubscription(new Subscription<SocketRequest, Notification>("btcusdt@bookTicker", request, n => handler(n.Data.Deserialize<BookPrice>()!))))
    {
        _logger.LogDebug("Could not subscribe");
    }

    _logger.LogDebug("Successfully subscribed");
}

public async Task UnsubscribeTickerAsync()
{
    var request = new SocketRequest("UNSUBSCRIBE", new[] { "btcusdt@bookTicker" }, GetNextRequestId());
    await SendAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false);

    if (!_subscriptionManager.RemoveSubscription("btcusdt@bookTicker"))
    {
        _logger.LogDebug("Could not unsubscribe");
    }

    _logger.LogDebug("Successfully unsubscribed");
}
```

Does that `Task.Run` count as multiple await?

```cs
private void OnConnected(object? sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _logger.LogTrace("Connected");

    _keepAliveTimer?.Start();

    foreach (var subscription in _subscriptionManager.GetSubscriptions())
    {
        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            await SendAsync(subscription.Request).ConfigureAwait(false);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you saying you'll be awaiting the `ValueTask` more than once?

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar, well if `SendAsync` has to be ValueTask too, it's being called multiple times, so it's awaited multiple times

Comment: One doesn't really necessarily follow the other. There isn't a single `ValueTask` after all. If you're calling it multiple times, then clearly you have multiple `ValueTask` results.

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar, fair point, edited the question. Take a look at `OnConnected`. Does that count?

Comment: You're not evaluating the same ValueTask twice, so no. `var task = SendAsync(...); await task; await task;` would be a different story.

Comment: Maybe Stephen puts it more clearly? => https://blog.stephencleary.com/2020/03/valuetask.html (pun intended).

Comment: @Fildor, Oh, I think I got it. Consuming it multiple times is like `await await Task.WhenAny(t1);`. Stephen explained it well